# Python regex fix bad json-string

Tags: python, arrays, json, regex, list

I have a bad/corrupted json-string and I would like to repair it with some regex.

currently my json-string looks like this

```
{'key1': ['value1'], 'key2': ['value2'], 'key3': 'value3', 'also-value-3', 'key4': 'value4', 'key5': value5}
```

What I would like is to parse occurrences like `'key3': 'value3', 'also-value-3',` into an array/list like in e.g. `'key1'`:

```
{'key1': ['value1'], 'key2': ['value2'], 'key3': ['value3', 'also-value-3'], 'key4': 'value4', 'key5': value5}
```

This kind of "comma-separated list" does occur multiple times and I was not able to fix it with and `re.sub` statement so far.

It would be nice if some regex-expert here has some insights/solutions to share as I am not an regex-expert...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regex is not suitable for JSON. Why does your JSON string look like that in the first place? You should fix whatever wacky system is producing that string. Maybe it's not supposed to be JSON.

Comment: I would also be worried about `value5`. If it's not a primitive data type then it should be a double-quoted string.

Comment: not possible. know that it is not ideal. but need a solution.

Comment: You need to write a custom parser if you can't fix the creation method.

Comment: It's not even close to JSON. For instance, it uses the wrong kind of quotes.

Comment: This doesn't look like something a regex can parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I provide no warranty but if you're desperate then something like this could work:

```
: ('[^']+'(?:, '[^']+')+)(?=,)
```

https://regex101.com/r/fwPRwN/1/

Comment: @dnks23 You're welcome but I still supply no warranty to my regex. It might fix your issues or make things drastically worse. Make sure to save a copy of your original data.